# How to use FactoryGirl to create data with has_many through association and some not null column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constraints, factory-bot, has-many-through, activemodel

I have a model like this

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :details, :through => :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :detail
end

class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

and I want to create an article with detail, so that’s what I do

```
factory :article do
  title "My Title"
  text  "My Text"

  factory :article_with_detail do
    after(:create) do |article|
      article.details << FactoryGirl.create(:detail)
    end
  end
end

factory :detail do
  content "My Detail"
end
```

It works fine for now, but when I want to add some constraint to my model ‘comment’ that make the commenter column can’t be null

```
class ChangeCommentCommenterToNotNull < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :comments, :commenter, :string, :null => false
  end
end
```

now I run rake spec will got an error says:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: comments.commenter: INSERT INTO "comments" ("detail_id", "article_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

How can I get around with this? Please Help~

Answer (score 0):

How does your `Comment` factory looks? `commenter` attribute should be set to smth to not be nil.

EDIT:
create new factory file `Comment` in your `factories` directory (remember to set `commenter` to smth).

```
factory :comment do
  commenter "first comment"
  body "Great article!"
  detail
end
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Comment: Oh? I don't know where to set up my Comment factory in my case? Since I    only create a detail and push (<<) it to my article. What I see the database do it that it will create an empty comment with only article_id and detail_id value, but now I need the comment to have some value in commenter, I don't know where to set it up.

Comment: I create a Comment Factory and change the detail like you said

### factory :comment do
    commenter "first comment"
    body "Great article!"
end ###

but it still doesn't work, now I will get:

"NoMethodError:
       undefined method `comment=' for #<Detail:0x007ffb6a300a30>"

Comment: Yeah ok, I mixed it up. There should be no `comment` in detail factory, because `Detail` has many comments. Try to add `detail` to Comment factory.